# How to auto repeat iterative calculation when parameters change?

Tags: google-sheets, iteration

I found that when Iterative Calculation is turned on in Google Spreadsheet settings, the following will work:

Cell A1: `100`

Cell B1: `=if(B1>0,A1-1,"Reached")`

However, it fails when cell A1 is changed, say to 200. What is displayed in B1 will be 199, or 1 less of whatever value has entered in A1.

In order to force a refresh, I have to cut-and-paste the two cells above to get it to work.

Anyone can explain the above phenomena or how to overcome it?

This is running on Google Sheets, using Chrome on a Macbook Pro.

Comment: makes no sense. can you explain in detail what are you after?

Comment: I am experimenting with Google Sheet's iterative calculation.  The example here is a simple countdown.  Cell B1 should keep recalculating its value as long as its value is > 0, and its current value is A1-1.  When first run, it works. But this does not work automatically again when A1 value is changed.